# Per-tensor post training quantization for tf2

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

Model trained using tf2 is going to be run on hardware which has performance benefits if model quantized '[per-tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/quantization_spec#per-axis_vs_per-tensor)'. But there is no any option for `TFLiteConverter` to make it 'per-tensor' for tf2. I guess tf2 can only do 'per-axis' quantization.

I'm sure that the model is converted 'per-axis' because `interpreter.get_tensor_details()` shows the following for conv2 tensors.

```
{'scales': array([0.00020375, 0.00016656, 0.00019717, 0.00022204, 0.00015516,
       0.00018166, 0.00017471, 0.00016947, 0.00020444, 0.00017661,
...], dtype=float32), 
'zero_points': array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...], dtype=int32),
'quantized_dimension': 0}
```

In case 'per-tensor' `scales` and `zero_points` would have been scalars. The model and training code are built for tf2 and converting all the things to tf1 would be nightmare.

1. Can I quantize tf2 trained model in 'per-tensor' manner?
2. Is it possible to convert tflite 'per-axis' to 'per-tensor'? Looks like I just need only to take mean from `scales` and `zero_points`.
3. Is it possible to train tf2 model in 'tf1 mode' without big changes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Set converter._experimental_disable_per_channel = True

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).